# Issue with passing variable through query string with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask route that sends a variable as a query string when it is processed (i have a default of `None`, because the first time this template is rendered no token is needed, or passed) :

```
@app.route('/results/', methods=['GET', 'POST'], defaults={'token': None})
@app.route('/results/<token>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results(token):
    tags = request.form['text'].replace(' ', '').split(',')
    data = fetch_data(tags=tags, next_page_token=token)
    processed_data, token = process_data(data=data, tags=tags)

    return render_template('results.html', data=processed_data[:1], token=token)
```

this is the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">

<h1>{{ data }}</h1>

<form action="{{ url_for('results', token=token) }}">
    <input type="submit" value="More results plz" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

For some reason when I click the submit button I get a `400` error `10.51.50.1 - - [13/Jul/2017 18:00:45] "GET /results/J0HWWe1OgAAAF0HWWey_wAAAFoAKAA%253D%253D? HTTP/1.1" 400`

and this loads on the page

```
Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

I think part of the issue is that the `?` is after the token i'm passing through, but i'm not sure why.  Also when i try to print `request.args` I don't get anything.

Any thoughts on how to properly send the token back to the route?

Answer (score 0):

You have this line in your view function:

```
request.form['text']
```

but I can't find a `<input>` in your template named `text`.